# Winter Bash Rehash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

Why is the [2019 Winter Bash](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/) using the same knitting theme as [2018](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/19/winter-bash-2018)? Have we run out of ideas?

Comment: Perhaps, but at least participation is voluntary.

Comment: In case you've been living underneath a rock the whole autumn, [this would be why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper).

Answer (score 15):

Yes, Winter Bash 2019 is using essentially the same theme as Winter Bash 2018. This is the unfortunate result of limited developer time and assignment of priorities.

In [the words of Stack Overflow developer Yaakov Ellis on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337910/winter-bash-2019-is-it-happening-this-year/339591#comment1134022_339591):

> It is the same theme as 2018 (and yes, you can knit once more). Sorry, not enough bandwidth here to make a brand new theme this time around. And the knitting is pretty cool. (Mostly) different hats and missions. And even though it is starting on the 9th, it will run through the end of Jan 1 (as usual)

[The official announcement on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/09/tis-the-season-for-hats-join-us-for-winter-bash-2019) by Cesar Manara provides confirmation:

> This year is a special one for the Winter Bash tradition. A hectic end of the year (that included a company-wide Meetup and a ramped-up focus on delivering improvements across other parts of our Q&A experience) means this year’s Winter Bash theme is the same as last year’s. But don’t despair, last year’s theme was awesome!
>
> We’re continuing to bring the fun. Winter Bash 2019 showcases a wild retrospective of hats that have been featured over five years, from 2014 to 2018. You can upgrade your avatar with some of the favorite hats from the past, as well as discover a couple of changed triggers for secret ones.

I, for one, think this is reasonable. We get to have the fun of Winter Bash, without wasting significant developer time and resources on a transient event.

I don't really think the knitting is all that cool, but…hats are fun, and at least we get a few new hats this year.

Like the one that is making everyone bump old Meta posts. C'mon folks—if you're going to edit, at least make your edits correct and non-trivial. I'm getting tired of having to roll back edits to old Meta questions that *break* the grammar, and it's only a few hours into Winter Bash 2019.

Comment: Even if the edit doesn't break the grammar I have to wonder what the big point of bumping a post from 2015 just to fix a spelling mistake is. This is why I never liked winter bash.

Comment: That advice could turn into a self fullfilling prophecy ... :)

Comment: What advice, @Jonas? Not wasting developer time on silliness like Winter Bash? Not bumping old Meta posts by making trivial or incorrect edits?

Comment: Is this why I've seen the blitz of almost pointless edits on meta.  I was wondering why so many higher rep users were making so many edits

Comment: Heh, heh. "assignment of priorities". Like shipping code on a Friday?

Comment: Not sure what assignment of priorities has to do with shipping code on a Friday, @JL2210. I agree that shipping code on a Friday is not a good idea, but assigning priorities based on the relative usefulness and impact of a feature seems to be a good idea to me.

Comment: That was an allusion to something that anybody on Meta should be familiar with.